# WPF Grid and content is pushed out of window after an animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, prism

I have animated the height of the content of one of my Grid rows so that the row extends downwards when a button is pushed (flyout style from 0 to 80px). This causes the next Grid row to get pushed the same amount downwards and hence out of the window. I am using Prism WPF and the content in the rows are imported via `<ContentControl>`'s.

I've tried to use Snoop to figure it out, and it looks like the height of the third Grid row does not update when the animation of the first row is fired. The third row contains a `<DataGrid>` wrapped in a `<Grid>`.

The outer code looks something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <!-- For flyoutButtons -->
           <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource FlyoutButtonRowHeight}"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:Regions.FlyoutRegion}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>       
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:Regions.DataGridRegion}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

The animation is defined as a `<Grid.Style>` element within the first `<ContentControl>`, and it is triggered via a `<DataTrigger>`.

So my question is how can I make the height of the last Grid row upate when/after the animation is triggered?